# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'chats')

Tags: reactjs, arrays, json, object, fetch

I am trying to fetch the data from this API "http://3.111.128.67/assignment/chat?page=0"

This contains an object with an array named chats.

I fetched the data successfully, but when I tried to access the chats array it throws this error

I am using react.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const url = "http://3.111.128.67/assignment/chat?page=0";

export default function Body() {

    const [data, setData] = useState(null);




    const fetchData = async () => {
      
            const response = await fetch(url);
            const jsonData = await response.json();
            // console.log(jsonData);
            setData(jsonData);
        

    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [])


    return (
        <div className="mt-40 flex justify-between">
            <hr className="border-t-4 w-[35%] mt-2 border-gray-300" />
            <div className="text-gray-300">20 May,2023</div>
            <hr className="border-t-4 w-[35%] mt-2 border-gray-300" />

            {/* Chats Area  */}

            {

                data.chats.map((item) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={item.id}>
                            <h1>{item.message}</h1>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }


        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything else is okay with your code except one tiny thing. You're getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'chats')` because when your component is rendered, `data` is set to `null`. `data` is not an object and there's no `chats` property.

You can fix this by ensuring that you only read `chats` after data from the API is available by using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) (MDN Docs):

```
   {/* Chats Area  */}

        {

            data?.chats.map((item) => {
                return (
                    <div key={item.id}>
                        <h1>{item.message}</h1>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }
```

This way, `data.chats` will be undefined at first render and React won't throw an error.